# 2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having another problem Beginning Ruby on Rails 4th edition page 155.  I tried to create a new user but I got an error message like this
    2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:

- Password is too short (minimum is 4 characters)
- Password can't be blank

All though the password was not short and blank.  According to the book, I added this params on users_controller.rb file.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password_confirmation)
end
```

I tried to find an answer from stackoverflow archives but I did not get a clear answer the way I could understand.

I thanks to all of you for giving me the right answer to my previous question.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `:password`  to the strong params permit list:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```